# Calling a Javascript function back in the web page from a .js library

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new to Javascript, so take that for what it's worth.

So, I have three validation paths in my code. The paths occur on different pages. My thought was to put the validation code in the pages, and invoke and act on them from an included library. On the pages they'd all have the same namespace name and function name, thus giving me some nice polymorphism.

Thus, in a.html:

```
<script>
if(typeof INSTANTFEEDBACKVALIDATE === "undefined") { INSTANTFEEDBACKVALIDATE = {}; }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/static/js/b.js"></script>
...
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.submit-request').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    INSTANTFEEDBACK.do_stuff();
    $('#myform').submit();
}
})
```

then in b.js:

```
(function(){

INSTANTFEEDBACK.do_stuff = function(){
    if(INSTANTFEEDBACKVALIDATE.validate()){
        do_shared_valid_stuff();
    } else {
        do_shared_invalid_stuff();
    }
}
})
```

then back in a.html:

```
(function(){

INSTANTFEEDBACKVALIDATE.validate = function(){

    // validation code
}
})
```

where I run into trouble is on the way back--on the call to INSTANTFEEDBACKVALIDATE.validate() it's not finding the INSTANTFEEDBACKVALIDATE global. Or at least that's how I interpret this message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'validate'
```

Anyone got any ideas? Or maybe a better way to do this?

Comment: I think you need a (var) in front of it to declare it -- http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/functions/

Comment: I wouldnt do it this way... The last one wants IMO is business logic stuffed in page level JS. The only thing running at page level should be initialization calls to library modules and perhaps event bindings (though id argue you put the event bindings in the lib/modules as part of the init process).

Comment: @prodigitalson Just out of interest, you mean something like this structure -- http://nativedroid.godesign.ch/res/js/script.js

Comment: @Tasos to some degree yes though there are alot of things hard coded there that i would probably make parameters via some kind of options hash(es) to an init method(s).

Comment: @prodigitalson I would agree if the validation in question was more than 'did they enter something in this field.' I didn't post that stuff just because I didn't want to distract people with irrelevant details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a.html, you need to invoke your function like so:

```
   (function(){

        INSTANTFEEDBACKVALIDATE.validate = function(){

        // validation code
        }
    })();
```

Note the '();' at the end. Without this, you're just declaring the function but not invoking it.

Comment: I didnt know that myself, cheers, ill stick that in my notes :)

Comment: Yup, that was it. Oops. Like I said, I'm a newbie with Javascript.